# Set <div> heightbase on <image> inside <div> height

Tags: javascript, c#, css

I am doing a base method to create a button CreateButtonBase(BtnOptions); on C#.

Here is the structure of a button:

```
<div onClick="someOnclickFunc">
    <image src="/someimage.png" height="someHeight">
    <span>SomeText</span>
</div>
```

BtnOptions include height that needs to be set for the button. And I have some problems there.

I can set attribute height for an , but it will not have any effect on the height of whole . The height of a div depends on the font-size. If i just change height using a css height with inline-style (which is incorrect) the button will be cut and not shown properly.

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: It looks like you wanted a `<button>` with a background image

Comment: can i set a height to the background-image as I do with the image 'height' attribute?

Comment: Check [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

Comment: the thing is that the image source and image height can differ so I will have to use inline styles to change background-size and background-image